# Using SVN and Working on Same File

Tags: svn

I'm new on using SVN. We work on an embedded project with 3 people. While someone is developing a c library the other ones are developing another libraries. There is a main.c and we are also coding somethings in it. My question is how do we manage the common files like main.c in SVN ? We need to do this because we all work together at the same time.

Comment: You really need to read the manual. SVN is designed for this. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning:

1. Install a subversion server on the server machine
2. Setup a repository
3. Setup users an access rights for them
4. Each user installs a subversion client on his workstation
5. Import your project into the repository (the initial commit)

   `svn import <project-dir> <repo-url>/trunk  -m="initial commit MyProject"`
6. Each user now checks out a `working copy`

   `svn checkout --revision HEAD --depth infinity --force <repo-url>/trunk <project-dir>`

Now you and your friends can start working each on his `working copy`. When done `commit` your changes to repository.

`svn commit <project-dir | some-file> -m "some comment: fixed bug or somthing"`

To get the changes of your friends execute an `update` command.

`svn update --revision HEAD <project-dir | some-file>`

Finally, here some links you might find interesting:

[svn quickstart](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.quickstart.html)

[svn server (linux)](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html)

[svn server and client (windows)](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion)

[svn command line client](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)

Answer (score 4):

When you make changes to the file and are ready to commit those changes back to source control, you commit them to the SVN server.  When somebody else also has changes to that file and they try to do the same thing, the server will tell them that there's a new version and they need to update first.

Upon updating, SVN will merge the changes for them.  If the merge is not easy, it will require the user to resolve conflicts (likely in some sort of merge tool, which I imagine is customizable).  Once those conflicts are resolved, that person can then commit their changes to that file as well.

The server always has the "current version" of the source code.  And when committing to the server it is the developer's responsibility to make sure they have tested their changes with the current version and aren't breaking it.  You can employ continuous integration tools and techniques to automate a lot of this, especially if you have automated tests for your code.  To reduce the complexity of merges it is recommended to commit many small changes instead of few large changes.

Comment: I don't trust merging for changes of main file, but I will try that with small changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that our tools can cover already. There are two things to be aware of.

- A merge tool

This is a tool that merges changes together automatically. Often the merge on the same file with two edits will occur without any problems because the edits touched different areas of the code.

- Conflicts

A conflict occurs when the merge tool finds both files have changed the same lines of code (its usually very smart about this too so it wont get pissy about blank lines for example) SVN will inform you of this issue and the client you use might even pop-up the merge tool showing you the problem. You will have to manually resolve your conflicts but with a little bit of communication this is rarely a problem.

Just remember to perform an UPDATE before you start working on new stuff to get everyone else's changes in otherwise you might end up with completely avoidable conflicts.

For the record I use TortoiseSVN and WinMerge as my client and merge tool.

Hope that helps!