# How can I use SVN as version control for developing small website with 2 developers at home?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am going to develop a small website with my 2 more friends. We all 3 will work on this project simultaneously. So it will be a problem to merge everyone's code manually. I am thinking that SVN could solve our problem. But I don't know how can I utilize it for personal use. Do I need to install it on a public server? Or where do I need to put it so that we all be able to share our code.

Thanks

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748215/using-svn-and-working-on-same-file/18748741#18748741), the server can be on one your workstations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Download and install [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) SVN server.

2.Install it in your local machine(any machine)

2.1 Default Repository location will be the installed directory, you can change it from properties.

3.Create Repository and add users.

4.Download and Install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) the client for all machine where you will commit / use it can be the same machine.

5.Import any code or files to the repository.

6.Checkout and then use.

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use a free code hosting website like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). There you can host your code and every teammember can access the code.
You can access your code via Git or Mercurial. So you can avoid installing a seperate server.